# Gnuplot Hanging Under Windows 10

Tags: windows, gnuplot, freeze

I have installed Gnuplot on a new Windows laptop, with all of the Windows updates applied and I am finding that Gnuplot is working fine in interactive mode but when I pipe data to it the graphs plot but I can't interact with the graphs via the mouse becasue the window freezes and says "Not Responding".
Interestingly, I can continue to pipe data to Gnuplot and the graphs are all plotted correctly.
I've tried 5.2.8 and 5.4.1 and I do not have any problems with either, on my old laptop with all the same Windows updates.
I'm at a loss! and wondering if it is somehow related to Microsoft anti-virus, anti-malware etc. I've tried disabling all of these but makes no difference.
I'm hoping that someone here might be able to give me some suggestions to try.
Thanks very much, as always,
John

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem under Windows 10.  As best as I can determine from the bug reports on the gnuplot issue tracker, the problem is specific to gnuplot 5.4 + Windows 10. One reporter suggests that reversion of commit 651af626 would fix the problem (at the cost of significant slowdown), but I have not seen confirmation of this by other testers.  If you can build from source and confirm that fix it would be a great help.

See https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2412/

Comment: Hi Ethan,
Thanks so much for the quick response.
I searched for possible bugs and found some similar but not exactly the same as this.
I have confirmed that, despite my earlier comment, this is not present in 5.2.8. I thought I had tested this reversion (v5.2.8) a few days ago but I must have been mistaken because it is definitely working now.
I'm going to be out of the office for the next few days so I won't have access to my dev laptop so I'll try and build the reversion of commit 651af626 next week
All the best,
John